# Fitbit OAuth2 refresh token returns invalid_grant

Tags: oauth, elixir, phoenix-framework, fitbit

I'm trying to refresh the Fitbit access token by using the refresh token.
Now as mentioned [here](https://dev.fitbit.com/reference/web-api/oauth2/#refreshing-tokens) on the Fitbit API documentation, there are a few requirements when trying to POST to https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token.

**Header requirements:**

> The Authorization header must be set to Basic followed by a space, then the Base64 encoded string of your application's client id and secret concatenated with a colon. For example, the Base64 encoded string, Y2xpZW50X2lkOmNsaWVudCBzZWNyZXQ=, is decoded as [client_id]:[client_secret].

**Body requirements:**

> grant_type (required) refresh_token Type: string
>
> refresh_token (required) The refresh token issued to you by Fitbit. Type: string

So in total the complete request should look like this:

> POST https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token
>
> Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOmNsaWVudCBzZWNyZXQ=
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=abcdef01234567890abcdef01234567890abcdef01234567890abcdef0123456

The example Fitbit shows above, is exactly what I have:

```
refresh_url = "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token"
grants = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=#{token.refresh_token}"
refresh_headers = ["Authorization": "Basic #{Base.encode64("my_app_id:my_app_secret")}", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

But then, when I actually try to get a new access token by using [HTTPoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison):

`HTTPoison.post refresh_url, grants, refresh_headers`

I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorType": "invalid_grant",
            "message": "Refresh token invalid: my_refresh_token. Visit https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2 for more information on the Fitbit Web API authorization process."
        }
    ],
    "success": false
}
```

Also, I'm completely sure the refresh token itself is 100% correct. I made sure it wasn't already used to refresh a access token. But just to be sure, I removed all the existing tokens and went through a new authorization code grant flow and then took that refresh token to try and issue another access token.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to use `"authorisation":` instead of `"Authorisation":`?

Comment: Hi @PawełDawczak, lowercase results in `Invalid authorization header format`.

Comment: Whenever you are dealing with OAUTH 2.0 issues, it is best to directly consult the RFC Standard. The meaning of the error message is that: `invalid_grant
               The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
               code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
               invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
               URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
               another client.` https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2

Comment: As such, I would advice that you sanity check the refresh_token you get from the authorization grant response. Put a binding.pry there, and ensure that you have the correct refresh token from the response. So after you do the authorization flow, like: `POST /token HTTP/1.1  
Host:server.oauth_provider.com  
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
Authorization:Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW

grant_type=authorization_code&  
code=SplxrhJY654090l&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb` (pardon me for the formatting)

Comment: you should receive a response `HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8  
Cache-Control:no-store  
Pragma:no-cache

{  
  "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",  
  "token_type":"example",  
  "expires_in":3600,  
  "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",  
  “example_parameter":"example_value"  
}` In that response, double check the expiry time and the actual refresh token and then retry your request and get back to us if it still fails.

Comment: @KevinJohnson Thanks for your responses. This is quite awkward, but I have two Fitbit applications registered and I was using the wrong credentials..

Comment: Yes, I guessed it was more of a user error than anything else, happy to see you figured it out : )